# Integrating inspinispan with jboss or spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss7.x, infinispan

I decided to freshly integrate infinispan. Also tried in both ways with basic example. First, integrating infinispan with jboss.
Second, integrating with spring(Already have spring application)
Which one is better in terms of flexibility and performance.

Answer (score 1):

In general - they should be equal in terms of performance because both integration modules (CDI and Spring) will produce Embedded/RemoteCacheManager under the hood.

Also, both are fairly similar in terms of features - Spring has [Spring Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations) and CDI can be used with [JCache annotations](http://infinispan.org/docs/8.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_use_jcache_caching_annotations). More complicated scenarios will require obtaining Embedded/RemoteCacheManager and implementing some custom code.

If you tell me more about your usecase - I might give you more accurate answer.

Comment: Thankyou. Actually I wanted to use expiry feature, I could not find the expiry attribute in the @cache annotation. I do not want to set expiry in xml. i wanted to give different expiry time at run-time. Now I am doing simply like this. cache.put(key,value, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); What is the equivalent of that in annotation?